# Windows 10 hide public desktop icons

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop, group-policy, public-folders

I have a windows 10 laptop at work. It's set up to show default icons on the desktop from the C:\Users\Public\Desktop folder. I hate that these icons clutter up my workspace but I have no privilege to delete them, and I think even if they were deleted, some group policy would recreate them sooner or later.

How can I hide or remove them?

Note: In File Explorer, I have allowed to show hidden files and I want to keep it that way.

Comment: @Leun4m that’s not a duplicate. The scenario is different and both proposed answers are not going to work. The OP doesn’t have the necessary permissions on the folder to do either suggested solution. That was stated in the question. Yet 4 people have voted to close this question based on this incorrect “duplicate.”

Comment: I'm sorry @Appleoddity, I might have misunderstood the question, but I can't see he pointed anywhere in his questions, he would have no permissions to permit read access to himself?! Even if he has no privilege to delete that should be possible.

Comment: @Leun4m  “but I have no privilege to delete them...” limited users don’t have access to change permissions on the public folders. He can’t deny read permissions to himself because he is already denied the ability to change permissions. The linked to answer, involves a scenario where the user has indicated they DO have admin access to those folders.

Comment: @Appleoddity Uh, now I see the point. I am sorry, I thought that was possible, even tried it myself, but my test didn't match the exact situation. He could maybe ask the admin, to change the permissions - My flag was torn apart.